# MariaDB: LOAD DATA INFILE block on reading file

Tags: mariadb

I have a table that looks like this (using MariaDB 10.2.36):

```
CREATE TABLE `eg_nat202109` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `log_device_ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_device_ipv6` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `dev_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_stamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dev_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_protocol` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_protocol` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ori_src_ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ori_src_ipv6` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `ori_dst_ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ori_dst_ipv6` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `ori_src_port` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ori_dest_port` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_src_ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_src_ipv6` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `rep_dst_ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_dst_ipv6` varchar(64) DEFAULT '' COMMENT,
  `rep_src_port` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_dst_port` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ori_vrfid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_vrfid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ori_input_bytes` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_input_bytes` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `die_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `l_vrfname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `g_vrfname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sn` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extendChar1` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extendChar2` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_device_mac` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_user_name` (`user_name`),
  KEY `index_ori_src_ip` (`ori_src_ip`),
  KEY `index_ori_dst_ip` (`ori_dst_ip`),
  KEY `index_rep_dst_ip` (`rep_dst_ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(`date_time`)
(PARTITION `part2021092900` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 01:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092901` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 02:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092902` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 03:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092903` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 04:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092904` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 05:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092905` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 06:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092907` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 08:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092908` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 09:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092909` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 10:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092910` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 11:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092911` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 12:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092912` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 13:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092913` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 14:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092914` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 15:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092915` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 16:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092916` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 17:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092917` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 18:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092918` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 19:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092919` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 20:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092920` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 21:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092921` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 22:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092922` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-29 23:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021092923` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093000` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 01:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093001` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 02:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093002` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 03:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093003` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 04:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093004` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 05:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `part2021093005` VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-09-30 06:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

I'm loading data use program from a file has 2,0000 data, the sql like this

```
load data local infile '" + fileName + "' replace into table "
                    + tableName + " fields terminated by '\t' " + cols + "
```

and then it run about minutes, the thread  seen not work, so I dump the stack information, it show like that

```
"NatLogPool-5" #158 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000560eee487800 nid=0xc5 runnable [0x00007f68dfabb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
    - locked <0x0000000087f869a8> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3011)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3472)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3905)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2491)
    - locked <0x0000000087f6e8f8> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2449)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    - locked <0x0000000087f6e8f8> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:415)
```

so I check the running state of a data base, it's block on reading file, and then it runing normal, it over and over again

I can't embed images now, you can see this situation easy by navicat server monitoring function.

I try other version, such as 10.2、10.2.40、10.3.31 even MySQL 8, them work well.

note: I use data base with docker redirectly.

Is this a bug in version 10.2.36?

I took the part of the code from the project, https://github.com/huangminwen/load-file-test, it only modify the database config in the yml file, I try 3 method on this test

1. load file way
2. by stream way
3. batch insert way

when you run this test code, please exeute the sql file, and the put the `eg_nat202109-1632813678309-588228.tmp` file on `/opt/inap/filedata/audit/loadfile` path, you can put it anywhere actually, but should modify the code `com.study.storage.NatLogSaveThread#FILE_PATH` at the same time.

It's about 15mins you can see the block on reading file.

Comment: Not that I can see [from the bugs fix list](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22load%20data%22%20and%20fixVersion%20%20in%20(10.2.37%2C%2010.2.38%2C%2010.2.39)). If you have it fixed in 10.2.40 is that ok? Who are you determining the "mariadb has lock, .. it's block on reading file, ... over and over again". Please edit details. Note there is a preview container `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.7-mdev-24621-innodb-bulk-insert` on improving load speeds. I should finish the [blog](https://mariadb.org/blog/) on it tomorrow. Any feedback welcome.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.

I'm sorry about the "mariadb has lock" , it's my mistake describe.

Any feedback welcome.

Comment: I supply some infomation what about code in the question above.